# Perform action if specific field is updated in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Rails (and Ruby for that matter).  I'm trying to trigger an SMS message via Twilio for verification if a user adds his/her mobile number to her account:

```
def update
 authorize! :update, @user, :message => 'Not authorized as an administrator.'
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 role = Role.find(params[:user][:role_ids]) unless params[:user][:role_ids].nil?
 params[:user] = params[:user].except(:role_ids)
 if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])

  if @user.mobile_changed?
    @user.update_attribute(:mobile_verified, false)
    #:message => 'You will receive an SMS shortly with verification instructions.'
    # Instantiate a Twilio client
    client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(TWILIO_CONFIG['sid'], TWILIO_CONFIG['token'])

    # Create and send an SMS message
    client.account.sms.messages.create(
        from: TWILIO_CONFIG['from'],
        to: @user.mobile,
        body: "Thanks for adding your mobile number. To verify, please reply YES to this message."
    )
  end
  @user.update_plan(role) unless role.nil?
  redirect_to users_path, :notice => "User updated."
else
  redirect_to users_path, :alert => "Unable to update user."
end
end
```

The account seems to update properly but my nested "if" statement is obviously incorrect becasue it's not working...any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add an after_save (or after_update) callback to your User model. The changed attributes will be available there.

Note: You should not update the current record from an after_save callback because you can end up in an infinite loop.

```
class User < ActiveRecord
  before_save :reset_mobile_verification, :if => :mobile_verified_changed?
  after_save  :deliver_sms, :if => :mobile_changed?

  def reset_mobile_verification
    self.mobile_verified = false
  end

  def deliver_sms
    # Code to send SMS
  end
end
```

#### EDIT

I see another answer was updated to do something similar, but using an after_commit callback. Depending on how you want your app to behave you could use either after_save (Twilio API error will cause the save to fail) or after_commit (Twilio API error will *not* cause the save to fail since it occurs after the database COMMIT).

Answer (score 1):

The `ActiveModel::Dirty` methods are tricky, they'll only return true while the object is *dirty*, i.e., when one or more of its attributes have been changed but before those changes have been written to the database. Once the object has been saved, such as by the first `if` statement's call to `update_attributes`, it's no longer dirty and `named_changed?` will return false. To get your `if` working, I'd suggest `if @user.previous_changes.include?(:mobile)`.

**Edit -** Additionally, you could also move this business logic to the model by using callbacks.

```
before_validation ->(user) { user.mobile_verified = false if user.mobile_changed? }
after_commit :send_twilio_verification, :unless => :mobile_verified, on: [:create, :update]
```